# Joining a thread / process in Java after some time - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, process, java-threads

I have the following method, which executes a command as a process and returns the ouput:

```
public String execute(String command) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

This code is great whenever the command returns, however for continuing running processes such as `top` this may never return. The code does not need to keep running continuously. It only needs to capture a snapshot, or it could time out after some time, such as 3 seconds. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

`Process` has a method `waitFor`. It can be used to force a timeout. For example:

```
if ((p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execPath)) != null) && !p.waitFor(TIMEOUT_CONSTANT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
    p.destroyForcibly();
}
```